# rospy message_converter outputs zero while in the terminal I got different output for the same topic

Tags: ros, rosmessage, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Kinetic
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5

I am using diff_drive_controller to publish rwheel_angular_vel_motor and lwheel_angular_vel_motor topics. My goal is to take messages published by those topics and transmit them via tcp/ip.

Currently, I am trying to convert ros msgs into a json file by using following script.

```
from rospy_message_converter import json_message_converter
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
  while True:
   message = Float32()
   json_str = json_message_converter.convert_ros_message_to_json(message)
   print(json_str)
```

When I run it I always see {"data": 0.0} in the output. But when I use:

```
rostopic echo rwheel_angular_vel_motor
```

I am able to see the data. I also used `rostopic info rwheel_angular_vel_motor` command and got the following output:

Type: std_msgs/Float32

Publishers:

- /gopigo_controller (http://R2:34603/)

Subscribers:

- /gopigo_state_updater (http://R2:45111/)

So anyone knows why I am getting 0 as output?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337386/rospy-message_converter-outputs-zero-while-in-the-terminal-i-got-different-output-for-the-same-topic/) by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-11-12**:
it seems that you define `Float32` msg and convert it without assigning any value. where do you subscribe to the topic `rwheel_angular_vel_motor` in your code?

**Comment by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on 2019-11-12**:
Actually, I am not subscribing to that topic. I am only reading `std_msg/FLoat32`. I thought since rwheel_angular_vel_motor publishes that message, I don't need to subscribe to that topic or the `from std_msgs.msg import Float32` part handles it itself.

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-11-12**:
`from std_msgs.msg import Float32` imports the definition of the message so that you can use it in your code. To access the data published on any topic, you should subscribe to that topic first. so, you need to write a subscriber to `rwheel_angular_vel_motor` and then assign the coming data to a variable and then convert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to **mali**'s comment I changed my code. Following script works for me. My topic name is `rwheel_angular_vel_motor` and it publishes `std_msgs/Float32` message. It turns out for converting messages to json package, json_message_converter is not necessary.

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
import json

def callback(data):
   rospy.loginfo("I heard %s",data.data)
   dict_data = {'rwheel': data.data}
   json_data = json.dumps(str(dict_data), ensure_ascii=False)
   print(json_data)


def listener():
   rospy.init_node('node_name')
   rospy.Subscriber("rwheel_angular_vel_motor", Float32, callback)
   # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
   rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  listener();
```

---

Originally posted by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) with karma: 57 on 2019-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0